# Handle corrupt install4j installer

Tags: java, install4j

I have created an installer using install4j and uploaded. But sometimes if the download is not proper we get a corrupt installer (got to know by checking the file size) and it shows following error with error code 34.

Also found thee error to be:

[0:27] verifying integrity length 304907802

[2:157] ERROR: check ReadFile failed 0 0 187816324

I found that this is related  to file size. But my question is how can we handle this in installer? As till this point we dont get control (ie.installer actions). I want to show custom error message on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When he installer file is damaged, it's not possible to to provide any meaningful workarounds. After this message, the installer will exit.